# Css Borders with Triangles

Tags: html, css, division, css-shapes

How can I create a div like this using html and css?

```
  ___________________
 <                   |
  |                  |
  |                  |
  ____________________
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kpe1k8p9/

Comment: you should provide an example with your attempts

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `div` or any other element as text box. Then by using the `:before` class, in combination with a transparent border (on 3 sides) you can create an arrow.

More info can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
div:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 10px;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 10px solid lightblue;
  border-color: transparent lightblue transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>Textbox with arrow</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll present you the fancy solution:

```
.box{
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 2px solid orange;
    margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
}

.box::after{
    content: " ";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: -12px;
    border-top: 2px solid #FFA500;
    border-left: 2px solid #FFA500;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 12px, #CCC 12px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex_Gr/3txq7s1e/)**